# Display Image on webform from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

The image is saved in oracle database in BLOB field.Now I want to show this image on my web form.I am using the code below but it's not working

C# CODE :

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
            dt=emppersonal.GetPhoto(Session["empcd"].ToString());
            byte[] barrImg = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["photo"];
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(barrImg);
            UserImage.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64String;
```

ASPX CODE:

```
   <asp:Image ID="UserImage"  runat="server" />
```

Comment: So what does "not working" mean? What does the resulting HTML look like? Is your code reached?

Comment: In which format mage is stored in Database?

Comment: It's not printing the image.I checked it by using breakpoint,it is getting the ImageUrl in base64string form that's why image is not getting print.

Comment: Image is saved in BLOB field in Database.

Answer (score 1):

try this. hope it helps

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = emppersonal.GetPhoto(Session["empcd"].ToString());
            byte[] barrImg = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["photo"];
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(barrImg, 0, barrImg.Length);
            UserImage.ImageUrl = "data:image;base64," + base64String;
```

Comment: this type of  UserImage.ImageUrl which i got from breakpoint :   data:image;base64TU0AKgAAAAgAEAD+AAQAAAABAAAAAAEAAAQAAAABAAABLQEBAAQAAAABAAABcQECAAMAAAADAAAAzgEDAAMAAAABAAUABQEGAAMAAAABAAIAAgEOAAIAAAIAAAAA1AERAAQAAAALAAADLgEVAAMAAAABAAMAAwEWAAQ

Comment: which extension of Image  is save in your database i.e jpeg,png etc?

Comment: Actually I am working in a company and I am trying to get the image from database,as I did not save these images that's why i don't know the extensions.How can i solve this problem because image can be of any extension

Comment: why don't you enter any dummy image of .jpeg and then retry? if problem exist? let me know

Comment: i misplace comma "**,**" after "data:image;base64, kindly updated from your side in coding

Comment: and you tried from dummy .jpeg image? , i have tried this code in many project and it successfully run

Comment: No,I don't have the access to insert the data in that table :(

Answer (score 0):

Create a ImageHandler.ashx file with the code as follows:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    try
    {
        string empcd = context.Request.QueryString["empcd"].ToString();
        string conStr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select photo from mytable where id = @empcd", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@empcd", SqlDbType.Int).Value = empcd;
        con.Open();
        string data = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        con.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(Convert.FromBase64String(data));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //if some exceptions will occur
    }
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And in your .aspx page:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgPhoto" ImageUrl="ImageHandler.ashx?empcd=some_value_here" />
```

You need to change a sql-query as you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: does not working still.I am trying to do it with HTTP HANDLERS.

Comment: Show your code after modifying my answer, what you have now

Comment: public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string empcd = context.Request.QueryString["empcd"].ToString();

        if (empcd != null)
        {
           
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = emppersonal.GetPhoto(empcd);
            byte[] file = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["photo"];
            memoryStream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
            context.Response.Buffer = true;
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(file);
            memoryStream.Dispose();

        }
    }

Comment: @AlinaAnjum I gave you another code. Just try to use that code fully, not only some parts. My code works for me in a various projects as I expect. You said that this still does not working, but still using your own code.

Comment: public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        string empcd = context.Request.QueryString["empcd"].ToString();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select photo from olphrm.emp_personal where emp_code=@empcd", Conn.getConn());
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@empcd", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = empcd;
        Conn.getConn().Open();
        string data = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        Conn.getConn().Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(Convert.FromBase64String(data));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

Comment: <asp:Image ID="UserImage"  ImageUrl="Handler.ashx?empcd=619"  runat="server" /> Still not working

Comment: I checked from breakpoint that there is an exception "Invalid character in Base64String";. How can I solve this

Comment: value in Data variable is "System.Byte[]"

Comment: System.FormatException was caught
  Message=Invalid character in a Base-64 string.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
       at Handler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in d:\projects\dev\Intranet\Handler.ashx:line 26
  InnerException:

Comment: You did not implement the `IDisposable` correctly. The call to `.Dispose()` should be in a `finally` block. Alternatively, use a using statement.